# Change sub view template via $state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Not sure if it's the best way to do this but I'm using angularjs ui router's multi views and I want to update the template/content of one of the views via some logic checking.

So I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
$state.current.views['filters@product_index'].template = 'OK!';
```

It works with the non multiview ones, so setting $state.current.template does work, but seem like setting it for multiple views state like the sample code above does not work.

Comment: Have you read about the templateProvider declaration on a state/view definition?

Comment: hi Chris, actually I'm using templateProvider, but maybe I'm not using it to the full extent yet? What I'm interested in is to be able to manually set a new template after the view is already initialized and the templateProvider already runs once.